# Error when I used javascript spin.js library

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp mvc and I need to use spin.js but is not working. Here is the code I am using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>spin.js example</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/1.2.7/spin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div>
    <script>
        var opts = {
            lines: 10, // The number of lines to draw
            length: 7, // The length of each line
            width: 4, // The line thickness
            radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
            corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
            rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
            color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
            speed: 1, // Rounds per second
            trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
            shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
            hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
            className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
            zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
            top: 25, // Top position relative to parent in px
            left: 25 // Left position relative to parent in px
        };
        var target = document.getElementById('foo');
        var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I run it a exception is showed in this line

```
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
```

and the message is

> "Spinner is not defined"

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Using the fully qualified path to the spin library, it appears to work fine when inserted here into the StackOverflow code snippet (literally copied your question, no additional modifications).  This would point to perhaps some other issue with your code (is this the entire page) or perhaps your browser has cached something that is causing an issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>spin.js example</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/1.2.7/spin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo"></div>
    <script>
        var opts = {
            lines: 10, // The number of lines to draw
            length: 7, // The length of each line
            width: 4, // The line thickness
            radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
            corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
            rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
            color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
            speed: 1, // Rounds per second
            trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
            shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
            hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
            className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
            zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
            top: 25, // Top position relative to parent in px
            left: 25 // Left position relative to parent in px
        };
        var target = document.getElementById('foo');
        var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the absolute url (with a scheme like http).

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spin.js/1.2.7/spin.min.js"/>
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I see that the spin.min.js is downloaded correctly, this problem is very strange because I can see examples in internet and they work but when I put that code in my application not work.

Comment: @user3303841 You must have another issue then. The exact code (with the http in the src) is working on my machine.

Comment: @user3303841 The only other thing I can think of is that the browser is not fully refreshing after you made the change. hit `CTRL + F5` to do a full refresh